# can you use max in this query?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, max

From this table, I'm trying to determine the nation (s) that have the highest number of teams (a nation X has a team if it has at least one athlete from that country X).

```
driver(id,name, team, country)
```

This solution restores all countries in descending order. Would it be possible to ensure that only the one (s) with the most team (s) return and not all of them? I think you should use the 'max' command but I'm not sure.

```
SELECT (country) ,count(distinct team) 
FROM driver
GROUP BY country
order by count(distinct team) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use your query as a CTE and then select from it like this -

```sql
WITH t AS
( 
 SELECT country, count(distinct team) cnt
 FROM driver
 GROUP BY country
) 
SELECT country, cnt FROM t
WHERE cnt = (SELECT max(cnt) FROM t);
```

Comment: thanks for the help ... would there be other solutions without using 'WITH' or is this the only way?

Comment: Yes, usually there is more than one way to write a certain query in SQL. The one above seems natural to me because it is roughly the same as if spoken in a human language - "from the list of countries and counts pick these with the highest count".

Answer (score 0):

You can combine this with a window function:

```
with counts as (
  SELECT country, 
         count(distinct team) as num_teams,
         dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct team) desc) as rnk
  FROM driver
  GROUP BY country
) 
select country, num_teams
from counts
where rnk = 1;
```

If you are using Postgres 14, you can use `fetch first` with the option `with ties`:

```
SELECT country, 
       count(distinct team) as num_teams
FROM driver
GROUP BY country
order by count(distinct team)  desc 
fetch first 1 rows with ties
```

If two countries have the same highest number of drivers, this would return both. Without the `with ties` option (which was introduced in Postgres 14) only one of them would be returned.